# Laravel email error, con correo de hostgator

Tags: laravel, email, host

En mi configuración de Laravel para enviar un correo electrónico de bienvenida, funciona correctamente si uso Gmail, pero cuando cambio a el correo que creé en Hostgator, ¡no funciona en absoluto!

Aquí mi configuración:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=`smtp`
MAIL_HOST=`mail.spaceweb.com.mx`
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=`noreply@spaceweb.com.mx`
MAIL_PASSWORD=`********`
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=`tls`
```

Y el principal problema es que **no hay errores**, el código no marca ningún error, simplemente no llega el email.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: puedes cambiar el puerto al 465, es el que yo uso en mi proyecto de laravel para correos de hostgator.

Comment: con la encriptación SSL o lo dejo igual TLS?

Comment: tecnobyte - No necesitaste hacer alguna configuración al servidor o a los correos?

Comment: Hice una prueba enviándome a mi mismo "noreply@spaceweb.com.mx" y funciona, pero si quiero enviar a otro no llega el email